# TOC with two columns and title above the columns

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

I am writing a document in which the chapter and section names are very short (dates). This makes a TOC set along the entire page width look rather silly.

Thus, I would like to set a TOC in two columns, with the TOC title above the colums for aesthetic reasons.

Trying different solutions, I have not managed yet. Please find an MWE below.

My attempt:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}

\section*{Contents} % Manually create heading 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % Remove heading name from TOC

% TOC with two columns
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with two columns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a KOMA-Script class, you can just use `\BeforeStartingTOC` and `\AfterStartingTOC` to add the `multicols` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{multicol} 

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\twocolumns` and `\onecolumn` would also be possible. But to get balanced columns for the last ToC page, you would additional need package `balance`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{balance}

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\balance\twocolumn}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\onecolumn\nobalance}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
  
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{balance}

\unsettoc{toc}{onecolumn}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn\balance
\tableofcontents
\onecolumn\nobalance

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
  
\end{document}
```

Both result in:

[image]

For more information about `\BeforeStartingTOC`, `\AfterStartingTOC`, `\BeforeTOCHead` and `\unsettoc` see the `tocbasic` chapter in the KOMA-Script use manuals (currently section 15.2).

Comment: Wonderful, this worked. Thank you. And here I am, yet again, wondering why I wasn't able to find this in the documentation myself!